# Find first occurance within a group of groups

Tags: sql, r

I have a table with 5 columns.

```
Country   Flow   %Rec    Date_Received(with timestamp)   Date
DE       DEF    10      2020-03-03 05:05:54       2020-03-03
DE       DEF    15      2020-03-03 07:25:24       2020-03-03
DE       DEF    20      2020-03-03 04:05:54       2020-03-02
DE       ABC    40      2020-03-02 03:05:54       2020-03-02
DE       ABC    50      2020-03-02 07:05:54       2020-03-02
DE       ABC    20      2020-03-01 06:05:54       2020-03-01
```

I want to find the % received of the last date and first occurance of date_rec. Output required:

```
Country   Flow   %Rec    Date_Received(with timestamp)   Date
DE       DEF    10      2020-03-03 05:05:54       2020-03-03
DE       ABC    40      2020-03-02 03:05:54       2020-03-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we can do `slice` after grouping by 'Country', 'Flow'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Country, Flow) %>% 
   slice(1)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Country, Flow [2]
#  Country Flow  `%Rec` `Date_Received(with timestamp)` Date      
#  <chr>   <chr>  <int> <chr>                           <chr>     
#1 DE      ABC       40 2020-03-02 03:05:54             2020-03-02
#2 DE      DEF       10 2020-03-03 05:05:54             2020-03-03
```

The above assumes that the 'Date' are `ordered` (in the OP's example it is already ordered).  If not, then convert to `Date` class and use `which.max`

```
df %>%
    group_by(Country, Flow) %>%
    slice(which.max(as.Date(Date)))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Country, Flow [2]
#  Country Flow  `%Rec` `Date_Received(with timestamp)` Date      
#  <chr>   <chr>  <int> <chr>                           <chr>     
#1 DE      ABC       40 2020-03-02 03:05:54             2020-03-02
#2 DE      DEF       10 2020-03-03 05:05:54             2020-03-03
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE"
), Flow = c("DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC"), `%Rec` = c(10L, 
15L, 20L, 40L, 50L, 20L), `Date_Received(with timestamp)` = c("2020-03-03 05:05:54", 
"2020-03-03 07:25:24", "2020-03-03 04:05:54", "2020-03-02 03:05:54", 
"2020-03-02 07:05:54", "2020-03-01 06:05:54"), Date = c("2020-03-03", 
"2020-03-03", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-01"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @shivamsarin where is the issue.  You said there is a typo in your data

Comment: @shivamsarin i updated wth the output I got.  I don't find any difference from your expected output (except for the order of rows)

Comment: With your code i'm not getting the max_date, I'm getting the first date of the group.

Comment: @shivamsarin np.  sometimes when we post an example, and if it is already ordered, then we go for the easy route because `slice(1)` should be faster, but `which.max` have to check the entire length to find the index of max value

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would use `row_number()` or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date_received = (select max(t2.date_received)
                         from t t2
                         where t2.country = t.country and t2.flow = t.flow
                        );
```

Comment: This also doesn't give the right answer. With this query I get only the max date.  After finding the max date I need the first time the data was loaded. The % received.